# Operate mouse by drawn paths?

Tags: mouse, cursor, bots

Can I set my mouse to follow a path? Not a recorded path but a drawn path? (with anchor points and handles) Better yet can I make it click at certain intervals?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - *No**

*Long Answer - You can do *anything*.

Since you are not talking about any specific software (not even a specific OS), this is a very general question. So the general answer is that yes, an application could be created to do what you are requesting.

There are many automation tools, such as [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), that can control the mouse. AHK has a quite robust scripting language, and GUI support. It may be possible to create a UI for path designing, which would save a file that the script could use as instructions to move the mouse. This would also allow for clicks to be inserted at any point you wish, clicks, right clicks, keystrokes, etc.

However I do not know of a tool that comes with the ability you are asking for out of the box (and no, [Superuser is not for finding software](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)). But aside from numerous automation tools that *might* be able to do this, it is certainly possible to write an application to do it (In a lower level language, such as C++) so the ultimate answer is *yes*.